# How to return variables and reuse them within other functions/methods within a Python Class

Tags: regex, xml, class, methods, return

I am working with a Python Class object project. One method name get_text() parses and extracts all of the text from an XML file and returns the value of text, 'text_variable' so that it can be used in another method with the Class. Within the Class object is a function called get_text. It reads the line of each XML file and then extracts all of the text. In this method, I wanted to store(return) the value of text under a variable name 'text_variable' retrieved from XML files (all of this input files are stored on my computer in a working directory) so that I can use it in another method within my program.

The'background_summary(self)' method,  uses a RegEx expression, searches and extracts sentences based on a keyword/phrase search with the returned variable from the previous method, 'text_variable' as a parameter. However, under the `if _name_=='_main_'` statement, when I tried to print the values of the return 'text_variable', it does not give me the all of the output I am expecting. It only prints one line from one XML file. However, when I print the 'text variable' inside of the `get_text(self)` method, it prints out all of the output from every XML file.

So I want to know what could be the possibility as to why I am unable to reuse and call my variable successfully when I run my program. The program is unable to retrieve all of the text from each XML file when called and it only retrieves one line from the first XML file. However, when I print the output 'text_variable' within the get_text() method, I can see all of the text; however, since the value is not returned, I am unable to use it inside the other 'background_summary()' method.

**CODE BELOW**

```
files = os.listdir(os.getcwd())

    class SummaryGenerator(object):

        def __init__(self,files):
            self.files=files

        def get_text(self):
            for f in files:
                with open(f,"r") as fh:
                    for line in fh:
                        soup=BS(line, "lxml")
                        tags=soup.find_all('p')
                        for t in tags:
                            info=''.join(t.text)
                            buf=io.StringIO(info)
                            if 'NOTICE TO APPELLANT' in buf.readlines():
                                break
                            else:   
                                words=info
                                text_variable="".join(words)       
                                self.text_variable=text_variable
                                return self.text_variable

        def background_summary(self):
            bg_list=[]

            background_corpora  = map(lambda x: x[0], re.findall('([^.]*?(respondent|filed a petition)[^)]*\))',self.text_variable, re.I))
            for b in background_corpora:
                bg_list.append(b)
            bkg_string = "".join(str(x)for x in bg_list)

            print('Background', bkg_string)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for f in files:
        Summary = SummaryGenerator(f)
        print(Summary.get_text())
```

Comment: That's a lot of code!  Please read about how you can create a [mcve], so that we can more easily help you.

Comment: Sorry. I think I edited to where it meets the MCV standards

Comment: @chrisz is that better?